# Adjust Width Content

Tags: css, reveal.js

On **reveal.js** can't find how to make the width of the content of the presentation wider. Tried editing **reveal.css** and the other styles but it appears the bounding box of all elements does not fill all the screen.

Whats the CSS property for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the width inside the file `reveal.js`. Just find `Reveal.initialize` and add the size you want. Example:

```
    Reveal.initialize({
      width: 900,
      height: 700
    });
```

Comment: Nice! That's it. On a 1920 x 1080 screen the following, on fullscreen, fills the screen completely. Gracias!

`Reveal.initialize({
width: 1920,
height: 1080,
margin: 0.00,
 });`